# No content provider found for permission revoke - Android

Tags: android, eclipse

i have a weired problem.
I want to install a app that i made on a Nexus 5 Phone and getting the LogCat error that i postetd below.
The funny think is, if i install this app on my Samsung Galaxy S3 it works fine. Just on my nexus 5 i get those errors and warnings.
And maybe i have to mention that the same OS is installed on both phones, CyanogenMod...

LogCat
http://pastebin.com/5dqdkKPY
android manifest:
http://pastebin.com/rtkeyVw5

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is you lack of permissions. try add this code to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER"/>
```

Comment: What does **INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER** allow?

Answer (score 0):

Every major android component must be declared appropriately on your applications manifest file. It seems like you are using a Content Provider. Is it a provider you implement? Or is it one of the Android's build-in? In any case you have to declare your "intentions" at the manifest. Take a look here:

```
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ProviderElement
```

Comment: Yes i'm using a ContentProvider in my FileProvider file (http://pastebin.com/HS4rA5J8). What exactly did i have to declare?

Comment: It depends on the provider you are using. What data do you wish to access from the provider? Calendar? Contacts?

Comment: I want to access Contancs

Comment: Then I suggest you follow this guide.
'http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html'
It will teach you everything you need to know in order not to bumb up into obstacles every once in a while and it is the quickest way to go.

Edit: The permission you need to add to the manifest is 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

Comment: Dude, it gets weireder :) Just did a fresh installation of my Rom, and voila, it works, i can install the .apk without changing anything in my project. I think there was a failure on my Nexus5. Thanks anyway for your help, and i will defenatly study your links, thanks for that!